# Cannot encrypt text twice with own encrypt function

Tags: c, while-loop, malloc, free

This is my program to encrypt a string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 255
char * encrypt(const char *c, int key){
    char *tmp = malloc(strlen(c)+1);;
    for(int i = 0; c[i] != '\0'; i++){
        tmp[i] = c[i]+key;
    }

    return tmp;
}

int main(void){
    char *dec = malloc(MAX);
    int key;
    int choice;
    do{

        scanf("%d", &choice);
        getchar();
        printf("Geben Sie den zu verschlüsselnden Text ein: ");
                    fgets(dec, MAX, stdin);
                    strtok(dec, "\n");
                    printf("Geben Sie den Schlüssel ein: ");
                    scanf("%d", &key);
                    getchar();
                    printf("encrypt(%s, %d) = %s\n", dec, key, encrypt(dec, key));
                    free(dec);

    }while(choice < 3);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I start the programm with the text `hallo` and the key `1` i get the text encrypt(hallo, 1) = ibmmp, which is correct, but when i do the second encryption with the same text and key(not starting the program again, but the second encryption when the while loop goes to the beginning) i get `encrypt(op�ŀ, 1) = op�ŀ`, which is apprently not what i want, but then, when i run the loop again it works, every time. So the first looprun works, the second fails and the third, fourth, fifth,... works again. I assume that there is a problem with the free() function, but I don't know what exactly the problem is. Can anyone explain this strange behaviour to me?

Comment: always check the returned value from malloc(), fgets(), scanf() to assure the operation(s) were successful.

Comment: the 'encrypt' function, to keep a properly defined string, the NUL terminator byte also needs to be copied, without modification by the 'key' value

Comment: #define'd values should always be surrounded by parens '(' and ')' to avoid certain problems.  while those problems are not showing in the posted code, it is a very valuable habit to form and will eliminate many long debugging hours later in your programming career

Comment: the 'dec' char pointer is only being malloc'd once, but is free'd on every pass through the loop.  1) should only be free'd after the loop exits.  2) writing to a malloc'd area after it has been free'd is undefined behaviour and can/will lead to a seg fault event

Comment: the 'user' is not prompted for the input value for 'choice', so the user has no idea (looking a a blank screen) what they should do.

Comment: @user3629249 i have commented the many printf() statements out, that tell the user what to do, to improve readability because it's not important for my free()/malloc() problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first call to `free` in `free(dec);` frees an object allocated by `malloc`. All successive calls to `free` free invalid objects as you are freeing multiple time the same object pointed by `dec`.

Moreover you never store the (`malloc`'ed) result of `encrypt` which leads to memory leaks.

Comment: And what should i do then, should I allocate space everytime i call encrypt(), or shouldn't i free the space because it's needed be succeding functions calls?

Comment: You should `free` in the same scope where you `malloc`.

Comment: i malloc at the beginning of main, so should free when i leave the while loop? Is this a general rule in c, or does this only apply to my situation? Anyways, now it works.

Comment: Every `malloc` needs a corresponding `free`. Also as a good practice `malloc` and `free` should be done in the same scope: in your example pass a `malloc`ed object to `encrypt` instead of doing it directly in `encrypt`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dangling pointer example. In your code you are allocating using `malloc` an object in the heap and referencing with a pointer. When calling `free` the object is deleted but the pointer still points to that location in the memory. In order to avoid these problems after freeing an object you should initialize the pointer to NULL (`dec = NULL`). So the second time you see garbage because the pointer shows in an address where used to be 'hallo' but it has been deleted.